# Vega of derivative when volatility is stochastic?

Tags: derivatives, greeks, self-study

What is Vega for a derivative when the volatility of the underlying asset stochastic process itself?

When the value of the derivative is $V_d$ vegais $\partial V_d/\partial\sigma$. Consider for instance SABR or Heston where $\sigma$ is a stochastic process, and **then I don't understand the mathematics and intuition behind $\partial\sigma$.** Can someone help me understand?

Comment: Some related posts https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/55641/how-to-calculate-vega-in-stochastic-vol https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/40984/vega-of-exotic-options